# Add CSS Transition between image switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my site I have a switch between a down arrow & and an up arrow. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4uLghzg7/)

How do I change this to a CSS transition, so there's a brief break between the switch?

Here's my code:

```js
function close_accordion_section(source) {
    $(source).parent().find('.accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $(source).parent().find('.accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

$('.accordion-section-title').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.active')) {
        close_accordion_section(e.target);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(e.target).parent().find('.accordion-section-content').slideDown(300).addClass('open')
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.accordion {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.accordion-section {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
.accordion-section-title {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_48px-512.png");
    background-size: 5% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
}
.accordion-section-title.active {

  background: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png") top right no-repeat;
     background-size: 5% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
.accordion-section-content {
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section"> <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">More information</a>

        <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
            <p>Text.</p>
            <p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are several errors. E.g. you should set `transition` property to the basic class (`.accordion-section-title` in your case). But the most important that there is no change of the property `color`. Why do you set `transition` for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways that I can think of.  One is by jQuery-UI and add a

```
.delay(2000)
```

to the end of your transition.  The other way is in your css class for your transition is do a

```
transition-delay: 2s;
```

For the arrow, it would be better to transition and rotate the image.

```
.rotate{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Here is a neat website to help you with that:  http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transition.html

Comment: This is excellent. Is it possible to 'fade' between the 2 graphics?

Comment: the best way is to not replace the image.  I will update my answer to do the image rotation.